# Webcam woes on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I haven't been happy with webcams on windows 10.  I have an old Logitech that works OK, with a logitech application that allows me to set zoom, pan, tilt, brightness, etc., and then launch whatever conferencing app I need to.

OK, now I try to upgrade to an HD cam.  Purchased a C922x from logitech.  There are no logitech drivers.  They expect me to run some silly game software to be able to effectively use this camera.  If I don't, I get a message about using windows generic drivers, and not being able to access full res.

Gave up, and decided to buy a Microsoft Lifecam Studio.  Silly me.  No way to control zoom in Windows 10.  I try to download and install the lifecam software, and Windows 10 gives me a "Lifecam can't run in Windows" security warning!!!

Searching around, it looked like YouCam7 was my option, but I'm getting antivirus quarantines.

So, my demands aren't great.  I want to be able to use my Lifecam Studio with webconference applications (in particular, Zoom), and be able to zoom my camera, just like I could two Windows OS's ago.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This isn't a request for software, but for any way to solve my problem-- be it an override to allow installation of the Lifecam software in Windows 10, some control panel option that can give me zoom functionality, better drivers, hiring an undergrad to physically move the camera in and out ....

I guess to summarize, my request is a solution to "how do I implement a webcam with full functionality in Windows 10?"

Comment: Can you recast this so it doesn't sound like a software recommendation question? I think there's a valid question in there somewhere, but it cannot be reliant on a 'software or learning materials' request. See the [help section](https://superuser.com/help) for further info - just bear in mind 'pure' requests tend to get closed pretty quickly [I haven't voted either way at the moment] Your profile tells me you understand the general SE structure... it's just here that 'requests' tend to get slapped a bit hard [sorry.]

Comment: No problem, @Tetsujin.  Generally, I'm not at this big of a loss, but I've been wrestling with this for months, and haven't gotten any closer to an answer other than "Cameras reek in Windows 10".  Obviously, I've spent considerable time searching SU, and still nothing.

Comment: Yeah, I think that ought to do it - assuming everybody's in a good mood today - you know what they can be like ;-) Personally, I'd go for the undergrad - they're usually compliant enough if you beat them with a big stick at least twice a day & provide unlimited pizza & beer ;-) {i'd have a great little off-topic software rec if you were on Mac, but idk of one for Win, sorry}

Comment: @Tetsujin  -- nice idea!  I'll see if I can whip up a little something on a mint VM!